# Label from Slider On fxml

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am new to javafx and cant quite get a way to have Labels from Slider from fxml, I have tried doing it from the main method and controller method and I didnt know which tag to use to call the method onDrag* didnt work without any success, any help shall really be appreciated, thanks in advance.fxml code is as below

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField amount;
    @FXML
    private Label percent;
    @FXML
    private Slider slider;
    @FXML
    private TextField tip;
    @FXML
    private TextField total;
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private Button clear;

    public void initialize() {
        button.setDisable(true);
        clear.setDisable(true);
    }

    @FXML
    public void keyHandle() {
        String text = amount.getText();
        boolean disableButton = (text.isEmpty() || 
        text.trim().isEmpty()) && (tip.getText().isEmpty() ||
                tip.getText().trim().isEmpty());
        button.setDisable(disableButton);
    }

    @FXML
    public void changeStateOfLabel() {
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> 
            observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                percent.textProperty().setValue((int) slider.getValue() 
                + "%");
            }
        });

    }

    @FXML
    public void calculate(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            int intAmount = Integer.valueOf(amount.getText());
            int tipAmount = Integer.valueOf(tip.getText());
            double intSlider = slider.valueProperty().getValue();
            double calculator = (intAmount + tipAmount * intSlider / 
            100);
            total.setText(String.valueOf(calculator));
            button.setDisable(true);
            clear.setDisable(false);
            if (slider.getValue() != intSlider) {
                intSlider = slider.getValue();
                calculator = (intAmount + tipAmount * intSlider / 100);
                button.setDisable(false);
                total.setText(String.valueOf(calculator));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input");
        }
    }

    public void clear(ActionEvent event) {
        slider.setValue(0);
        total.clear();
        amount.clear();
        tip.clear();
        button.setDisable(true);
        clear.setDisable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use pictures to show us your code. You should add it to your question

Comment: Probably adding a listener to the `value` property of the slider to update the label would work. "A label from a slider" is not a sufficient description of the desired behaviour thoug. Furthermore code required to understand the question needs to be posted as code block in the question itself. This way people interested in answering the question can simply copy&paste the code...

Comment: Sorry about that, forgive my ignorance